# Accessing VSTS Team Project Collection from cloud service

Tags: tfs, azure-cloud-services

My cloud service is trying to create a new team in VSTS using TFS APIs. Here is the code snippet -

```cs
var serverUrl = TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName("https://vsts_instace_name.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUrl, 
                                                 new AadCredential(username, password));
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

var vssCredentials = teamProjectCollection.ClientCredentials.ConvertToVssCredentials(teamProjectCollection.Uri);
ProjectHttpClient projectHttpClient = new ProjectHttpClient(teamProjectCollection.Uri,   
                                     vssCredentials);

var projectInfo = projectHttpClient.GetProject("TestProject");
var teamService = teamProjectCollection.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
var team = teamService.CreateTeam(projectInfo.Id.ToString(), "NewTeam", string.Empty, null);
```

The code works correctly in the local environment but fails in cloud. An exception is thrown at the line where it tries to retrieve the `projectInfo`. Exception is - `TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.`

Do I need to make any change in the authentication code?

Comment: Which username and password are you using? Do you use Personal access tokens? Check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-application-access-policies-vs

Comment: They are AD credentials of a service account which has access to that VSTS instance (basically that service account is a project collection administrator). I tried using personal access token but that too fails in cloud with exception `TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://vsts_instace_name.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.` when `teamProjectCollection.GetService<T>();` is executed. Hence I started initializing `TfsTeamProjectCollection` using AADCredentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Personal Access Token or enable Alternative authentication credentials and then trying with following code:

```
string tfsurl = "https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/";
string projname = "project";
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("alternativeusername", "alternativepasswordorpersionalaccesstoken");
BasicAuthCredential bac = new BasicAuthCredential(nc);
TfsClientCredentials tfcc = new TfsClientCredentials(bac);
tfcc.AllowInteractive = false;
TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsurl), tfcc);
ttpc.Authenticate();
ProjectHttpClient phc = ttpc.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
TeamProject pi = phc.GetProject(projname).Result;
```

Comment: Same output as earlier. It fails at `ttpc.Authenticate();` with exception message - `You are not allowed to access https://xxxx.isualstudio.com.` So far, I have been able to authenticate `TfsTeamProjectColletion` by using  AD credentials during initialization. After that, if I try to get `ProjectHttpClient` just like in your code, exception is thrown - `Resource not available for anonymous client. Client authentication is required`

Comment: @Saurabh What credential do you use?

Comment: I am using Active Directory credentials of a service account which is added as a Project Collection Administrator in the VSTS instance.

Comment: @Saurabh I mean what credential do you use with my code? It only works with alternative credential or personal access token.

Comment: Oh, ok, I used personal access token and kept username empty.

Comment: I issued a new Personal Access Token and tried the same code and it worked. Sorry my bad! :( I guess the earlier test token (whoever issued it) is expired hence it was not working..

Answer (score 0):

You may try to authenticate using Basic Authentication:

```
public static void BasicAuthSoapSample()
{
    // Authenticate using Basic Authentication
    NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(basicAuthUsername, password);
    BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
    TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
    tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;
    using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUri), tfsCred))
    {
        tpc.Authenticate();
        Console.WriteLine(tpc.InstanceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Cece-MSFT but I am hitting the same "not authorized to access" exception again at `tpc.Authenticate();`